# ImportError: cannot import name "urandom"

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I get this error when I try to `runserver` any of my projects while I'm running my virtual env (`workon django1.2`)

the error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name "urandom"
```

after researching the issue I found [this](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/news.html):

> Warning Python bugfix releases 2.6.8, 2.7.3, 3.1.5 and 3.2.3 include a change that will cause “import random” to fail with “cannot
>   import name urandom” on any virtualenv created on a Unix host with an
>   earlier release of Python 2.6/2.7/3.1/3.2,
>   if the underlying system Python is upgraded. This is due to the fact that a virtualenv uses the system Python’s standard library but
>   contains its own copy of the Python interpreter, 
>   so an upgrade to the system Python results in a mismatch between the version of the Python interpreter and the version of the standard
>   library. 
>   It can be fixed by removing $ENV/bin/python and re-running virtualenv on the same target directory with the upgraded Python.

but running `ENV/bin/python` gives me :

```
bash: ENV/bin/python: No file or directory of this type
```

Where can I find my virtualen directory?

I understand very little about virtualenvs so please bear with me

thanks

Comment: Note that `$ENV` is a shell variable representing the location of your _virtualenv_ it's not literally `ENV`.

Comment: @PedroRomano ok :p so how do I find that location?

Comment: Basically it will be the same directory where your virtualenv's `activate` script is. If you activate your virtualenv it is also in the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable.

Comment: @PedroRomano but I dont know where is my workon , I activate it using workon  +the name of the virtualenv

Comment: So you are using `virtualenvwrapper`, which makes it even easier: just use the command `cdvirtualenv` and it will change to the virtualenv's directory. After that the `python` you want will be in the `bin` directory.

Comment: @PedroRomano it worked, I removed the python directory,now I dont know how to do the second part : It can be fixed by removing $ENV/bin/python and re-running virtualenv on the same target directory with the upgraded Python.

Comment: This was an useful question with useful response, I would like to post an answer; the main python binary and the binary at the virtualenv got out of sync; just copy it over: activate the problematic virtualenv and issue `cat /usr/bin/python2.6 > \`which python\``

Comment: You can vote to reopen the question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to recreate your virtual environment.

My guess is that the following has happended:

1. You created a virtualenv
2. At some later point in time, the system's Python installation was updated with the urandom security bugfix.
3. Your virtualenv (created from a previous Python point release) does not work anymore (due to the issue you mention in your question)

The simplest fix is to delete your virtual environment and create a new one:

```
$ rm -r VIRTUALENVDIR
$ virtualenv VIRTUALENVDIR
$ . VIRTUALENVDIR/bin/activate

# then pip install any required packages, if your project has a requirements.txt file,
# this is simply:
$ pip install -r requirements.txt

# otherwise, you will have to install each package
$ pip install packagename
$ pip install packagename==version
```

Comment: Since you have `virtualenvwrapper` installed, the command to (re)create a virtual environment is `mkvirtualenv`.

Comment: ok I've done it but when I try to runserver my project I get python: `can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: What have you done? Used mkvirtualenv or recreated the virtual env using rm -r ... etc. described i my answer?

Comment: Do I really have to remove my virtualenv ? I'm afraid I will not be able to install all the packages since I'm not the one who created it at first and I dont know all the packages needed for the projects

Comment: Regarding the "can't open file manage.py" error: What command line causes this error? Do you run: ``$ python manage.py runserver`` ?

Comment: Regarding recreating the virtual environment: You can list installed packages in a virtualenv using the ``pip freeze`` command. Save the output of the command in a text file and do ``pip install -r filename.txt`` in the new environment.

Comment: You can use `rmvirtualenv` to delete a virtualenv.

Comment: Easy fix: `cdvirtualenv` and then `cat /usr/bin/python2.6 > bin/python`