# "ImportError: cannot import name urandom", virtualenv is not installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am running ubuntu 11.10 with python 2.7.2. When I import the random module I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

Googling shows that this appears to be a common problem among people using virtualenv. The solution usually proposed is to simply re-run virtualenv on the directory you're having trouble with. However, I do not have virtualenv installed. Could anyone offer me any guidance as to what to do?

I have looked at [ImportError: cannot import name "urandom"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194308/importerror-cannot-import-name-urandom); it did not help, since I do not have virtualenv installed (my $ENV is empty, just in case anyone was curious).

I have also looked at [Python ImportError cannot import urandom Since Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366821/python-importerror-cannot-import-urandom-since-ubuntu-12-04-upgrade); it also did not help, since I am not using virtualenv.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Python?  That often helps.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't change anything